# What does "vector" means in javascript graph library

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I am currently learning to use [Springy](https://github.com/dhotson/springy) which is a force directed graph layout algorithm in JavaScript. There is a demo code [springyui.js](https://github.com/dhotson/springy/blob/master/springyui.js) springyui.js , in the code, there are several places define "**vector**", e.g. `var targetBB = {bottomleft: new Vector(-2, -2), topright: new Vector(2, 2)};` .

I don't understand what is the mean of **vector** in javascript graphic application, what does **vector** defines generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 2D [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector). In that library  you could just consider it as a container of 2 numbers (*x*, *y*) representing a direction and magnitude on a plane.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but where is the original "0" point on the screen normally?

Comment: @Mellon: A vector does not have an "original point". It is a relative quantity, like a displacement.